# Node app failing during reactDOM.render()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run a existing React/Node application locally. It is failing on my index.js at the line where it calls reactDOM.render()

```
Module parse failed: C:\Users\dan\Documents\Development Projects\diy-data\client\index.js Unexpected token (30:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

When I try to run the file using

```
yarn start
```

It's failing on this section of code in index.js:

```
reactDOM.render(
<MuiThemeProvider>                
<Provider store={store}>
  <div className="container">
    <Header />
    <Leftnav />
    <Stepper />
    <UploadScreen />
    <TransformScreen />
    <ConfirmScreen />
  </div>
</Provider>
</MuiThemeProvider>,
root);
```

I assume I'm missing some kind of basic setup, but finding no information on this error.

Comment: You have to install `babel-register` and call `require('babel/register');` as your first line in node file. Also make sure you are on the latest version of babel. And you should render it as shown here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use either EXPORT or SET to create env variables and depends on your OS

```
"dev": "export PORT=3000 || SET \"PORT=3000\" && export NODE_ENV=dev || SET \"NODE_ENV=dev\" node --inspect=5858 server/index.js"
```

Comment: Thanks, apologies, I had updated the question significantly before your good answer, so I've upvoted it.

Comment: no problem, btw the problem you are having now is because react uses jsx which is not valid javascript and you need a transpiler like babel. If you are using React you for sure have to use babel and weckpack